# NTLM Authentication with ksoap2 in Android

Tags: android, authentication, ksoap2, ntlm

I am using ksoap2 3.6.

I am trying to access a soap web service secured with NTLM. I found the ksoap2-extra-ntlm-3.6.0.jar file and added that to my project, thinking this was my saving grace.

```
NtlmTransport ntlmTransport = new NtlmTransport(BASE_URL);
ntlmTransport.setCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, "");
ntlmTransport.call(name_space + method_name, envelope);
```

However, I get an unauthorized 401 response code. I have validated my username, password and domain via .NET and browser based authentication methods, so I know those are correct.

Question: how do I actually authenticate and get past the 401 code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the link from where you downloaded ksoap2-extra-ntlm-3.6.0.jar. I searched alot but unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

Since ksoap2 is open-source, I peeked at the code for NtlmTransport and altered the call method in the following way.

I removed:

```
BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, this.timeout);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    client.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NtlmTransport.NTLMSchemeFactory());

NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(this.user, this.password, this.ntWorkstation, this.ntDomain);

client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
```

and replaced that code with this code:

```
NTCredentials ntCredentials = new NTCredentials(user, password, ntWorkstation, ntDomain );

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY), ntCredentials);

HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
```

I wrapped the execute and response code with a try...finally block to close the client in the finally block. Works like a charm now.

I added

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

to my gradle file.

Thought somebody might benefit.

Thanks.